# Request body in express is undefined?

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, express, alamofire

I am making a simple POST request using Alamofire (in iOS) and handling it in node using express. 
My code in iOS:

```
    let boop: [String: AnyObject] = ["username":"fakeuser"];
Alamofire.request(.POST,"http://localhost:3000/test", parameters: boop, encoding: .JSON)
```

And this is my code in node:

```
    var app = require('express')();  
var http = require('http').Server(app);  
app.post('/test', function(req, res){
 console.log("THE SERVER HAS RECEIVED THE POST! \n")
 console.log(req.body);
});

http.listen(PORT, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

My terminal console prints out "the server has received the post" , so I know that the post is actually triggered. The issue is that instead of logging the req.body, it instead prints out "undefined". I've looked around and it seems like a "body parser" thing needs to be configured but apparently that is obsolete with the new version of express. So I am lost as to what to do.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to add the body-parser to your express app to parse the JSON.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

See http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#req.body.